# Uniqueness of points in Elliptic Curve addition

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

When working on a curve E, is the point yielded by P + Q (some P and Q on E) completely unique? What I mean is there are no other points on E sharing the same x or y value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general fact, a point is determined by its coordinates.

Elliptic curves are usually represented as plane projective curves, in which case they are described by a homogeneous relation between three projective variables $X, Y, Z$. If you are using a Weierstrass model then there is only one point with $Z=0$ (the "point at infinity"), so in this case yes, a point in the affine model is determined by the values of $x=X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$. However you cannot describe the point at infinity using the coordinates $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ignoring the point at infinity, can an x value be used as part of two different points on E? Or does each x value have a unique corresponding y value?

Comment: @thaweatherman No, in general there are two $y$-values. For instance if your curve is given as $y^2=f(x)$ then $(x,-y)$ is also on the curve (it's the inverse of the point $(x,y)$).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you. I ask because I am determining the effectiveness of a hash function at resisting collisions where the hash function takes the resulting x value of some point addition to represent the digest

Comment: @thaweatherman You are welcome, good luck with your project!